# Mock function with arguments as pointer

Tags: c++, unit-testing, hippomocks

I have a function:

```
void setData(int *ptr) {
   *ptr = 3
};
```

Can I use Hippomock to mock this function and set the value of `ptr`?
Something like: `mock.OnCallFunc(setData).With(int *ptr).Do({ *ptr = 5;});`

So I can do something like this later

```
int p;
setData(&p);
printf("value of p is suppose to be 5: %d\n", p);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write with a normal function or with a lambda

```
void setDataMock(int *ptr) {
  *ptr = 5;
}
MockRepository mocks;
mocks.OnCallFunc(setData).Do(setDataMock);
// Or
mocks.OnCallFunc(setData).Do([](int *ptr) {
  *ptr = 5;
});

int p;
setData(&p);
printf("Value of p: %d\n", p);
```